# form validation not working in codeigniter as expected

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I just started working on codeigniter and stuck with the form validation issue

here is my code
Controller :

```
public function indexnew(){
        $data['title'] = array('welcome'=>'text here');
        $this->load->helper('form');    

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

         $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');

        $this->load->view('come/come',$data);
    }
```

View:

```
<form method="POST" action="form">
        <h5>Username</h5>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" />

        <h5>Password</h5>
        <input type="text" name="password" value="" size="50" />

        <h5>Password Confirm</h5>
        <input type="text" name="passconf" value="" size="50" />

        <h5>Email Address</h5>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="" size="50" />

        <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
    </form>
```

the username validation is added but it's not working

someone please tell me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Give the form attribute  `action="controller_name/indexnew"`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to mention path in your action

```
<form method="POST" action="form">
```

it should be

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo site_url('controller_name/indexnew')?>">
```

write your controller name at controller_name.

you also have to set base_url in config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

I hope It works....!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this this code for your problem :

**Controller.php**

```
public function indexnew(){
        $data['title'] = array('welcome'=>'text here');
        $this->load->helper('form');    
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'required');
        if($this->form_validation->run()) {
            // Add here other stuff
            redirect('page_name');
        } else {
            $this->load->view('come/come',$data);
        }
    }
```

I hope it will helps.